# Complex Series Convergence of Quotient

Tags: complex-analysis

For $|z-a|<r$ let $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n (z-a)^n$.  Let $g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n(z-a)^n$.  Assume $g(z)$ is nonzero for $|z-a|<r$.  Then $b_0$ is not zero.

Define $c_0=a_0/b_0$ and, inductively for $n>0$, define
$$
c_n=(a_n - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} c_j b_{n-j})/b_0
$$

Note that the definition of $c_n$ implies that $a_n=\sum_{j=0}^{n} c_j b_{n-j}$ (it is equivalent to say $c_n$ solves this last equality)

So, we have a formal series (no claim yet to converging to $f/g$), $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n (z-a)^n$.  Call this the formal quotient.

### The problem is, we are to take the formal quotient for granted and prove that the formal quotient actually converges to $f/g$ for all $|z-a|<r$

I'm stumped, sorry.  I need a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know hat $f/g$ is holomorphic in $\{|z-a|<r\}$. Thus, it is equal to its Taylor series, that is,
$$
\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(z-a)^n,\quad|z-a|<r,
$$
where
$$
c_n=\frac{1}{n!}\,\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\Bigl(\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}\Bigr)\Bigr|_{z=a}.
$$
Now deduce the recurrence relation for the coefficients $c_n$ from
$$f(z)=g(z)\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(z-a)^n.
$$

Comment: I had to think about it but I get it now.  I'm slow sometimes.  Can you verify the following statement is correct? Assume I can deduce the recurrence relation and say that I conclude that the $c_n$ in your hint is equivalent to the coefficients for the formal quotient in the problem statement.  Then by the uniqueness of the power series representation I have shown that it converges to f/g.  Now I just need to plug away at it.

Comment: Yes, that reasoning is correct.